# Why `at` can't find `mail` even if it's in every path, including the systemd unit?

Tags: 20.04, mail, schedule, job-control, at-command

I'm trying to get the logs of `at`, which AFAIK are sent via local mail.

The problem I'm having (on Ubuntu 20.04) is that I've configured the mail, and the PATH, but any time I execute `at`, the syslog reports:

```
Dec 30 16:45:44 mymachine atd[5799]: Exec failed for mail command: No such file or directory
```

Specifically:

- I've installed `mailutils`; a test `mail` command runs successfully (no mail);
- The `mail` executable (symlink, specifically) is under `/bin` and `/usr/bin`; I've added a symlink also to `/sbin`;
- I've modified the systemd unit to: `ExecStart=/bin/bash -c "PATH=/bin:$PATH exec /usr/sbin/atd -f"` (and reloaded the system configuration, and restarted the unit)
- I've even launched `atd` manually, with the unit stopped, with the extra `$PATH`

and still, I get the same error. What's wrong?

Comment: Where's the symlink point to?  Is that symlink destination reachable by whatever user `at`/`atd` is running as?

Comment: According to `man at`, *"Mail will be sent using the command /usr/sbin/sendmail."*

Comment: @steeldriver thanks, that solved it! If you write it in answer form, I'll accept it.